# Cropping image doesn't work with UIImagePickerController setAllowsEditing:YES

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController to allow the user to choose a picture and have it as a profile picture. The problem is that "setAllowsEditing:YES;" doesn't seem to work. The cropping system thingy comes up, but when you've cropped and press "choose" the image appears uncropped. I've looked around on here, but I can't seem to find a good answer. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {

self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

self.chosenImage = info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.avatar setImage:self.chosenImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are getting original image not edited one. You need to capture edited image.

```
Edited Image (use this)
 self.chosenImage = info [UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

Orginal Image (not this)
self.chosenImage = info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.